# Is it possible to throttle upload bandwidth per `IP` basis using `tc`, `htb` and `iptables` ? (Download limitation not required)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tc, qos

**Problem**

I've searched `internet` like anything but couldn't find much about limiting `upload`.
The solutions given are not limiting `IP` basis like [this one](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/limiting-upload-with-tc-4175470860/) but LAN as a whole.

```
             +-----+
+--------+   |  S  |
| User A |---+  W  |
+--------+   |  I  |
+--------+   |  T  |     +--------+        +----------+
| User B |---+  C  +-----| Router |--------| Internet |
+--------+   |  H  |     +--------+        +----------+
   ....     ... / ...
+--------+   |  H  |
| User N |---+  U  |
+--------+   |  B  |
             +-----+
```

`UserA:172.16.10.2`

`UserB:172.16.10.3`     `RouterPrivate:172.16.0.1`

`UserC:172.16.10.4`

I want to limit only `upload` of `172.16.10.3` & `172.16.10.4` using `tc` `htb` and `iptables`

**What I've already tried**

> altered the script as per my requirement

```
IF_INET=external

# upload bandwidth limit for interface
BW_MAX=2000

# upload bandwidth limit for 172.16.16.11
BW_CLIENT=900


# first, clear previous settings
tc qdisc del dev ${IF_INET} root

# top-level htb queue discipline; send unclassified data into class 1:10
tc qdisc add dev ${IF_INET} root handle 1: htb default 10

# parent class (wrap everything in this class to allow bandwidth borrowing)
tc class add dev externel parent 1: classid 1:1 htb \
  rate ${BW_MAX}kbit ceil ${BW_MAX}kbit

# two child classes
#

# the default child class
tc class add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:1 \
  classid 1:10 htb rate $((${BW_MAX} - ${BW_CLIENT}))kbit ceil ${BW_MAX}kbit

# the child class for traffic from 172.16.16.11
tc class add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:1 \
  classid 1:20 htb rate ${BW_CLIENT}kbit ceil ${BW_MAX}kbit

# classify traffic
tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip src 172.16.16.11/32 flowid 1:20
```

but this will *not* work for limiting upload. So what's the solution?

Comment: Your [referenced link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/limiting-upload-with-tc-4175470860/) already does what you want. It limits by (source) LAN IP address. In your case you need to limit two IP addresses. In the example it limits one.

Comment: No! It will not work, it will take the default class's limitation speed, just give it a try by altering the rate and ceil of classes. **So my question remains same!**

Answer (score 0):

why did you use 172.16.16.11 as source IP instead of .10.3 and/or .10.4 ?!

I used local VMs (running "nc -klvp 42 >/dev/null") connected to a local open-vswitch interface. to demonstrate traffic shaping for some src IPs, I removed "ceil" parameter at "class 1:20".

**my tc script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export IF_INET=ovs-br0
export UNIT=kbps

export BW_MAX=2048
export BW_CLIENT=128

tc qdisc del dev ${IF_INET} root &>/dev/null
tc qdisc add dev ${IF_INET} root handle 1: htb default 10

tc class add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate ${BW_MAX}$UNIT
tc class add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate $((${BW_MAX} - ${BW_CLIENT}))$UNIT ceil ${BW_MAX}$UNIT
tc class add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate ${BW_CLIENT}$UNIT 

tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 172.16.10.3/32 flowid 1:20
tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 172.16.10.4/32 flowid 1:20
```

**local ip addresses/routes with different src IPs:**

```
section61:~ # ip a s dev ovs-br0 | grep 172.16.1
inet 172.16.10.4/24 scope global ovs-br0
inet 172.16.10.3/24 scope global secondary ovs-br0
inet 172.16.10.5/24 scope global secondary ovs-br0
inet 172.16.10.6/24 scope global secondary ovs-br0

section61:~ # ip route get 172.16.10.13 | grep -v cache 
172.16.10.13 dev ovs-br0 src 172.16.10.3 uid 0 
section61:~ # ip route get 172.16.10.14 | grep -v cache 
172.16.10.14 dev ovs-br0 src 172.16.10.4 uid 0 
section61:~ # ip route get 172.16.10.15 | grep -v cache 
172.16.10.15 dev ovs-br0 src 172.16.10.5 uid 0 
section61:~ # ip route get 172.16.10.16 | grep -v cache 
172.16.10.16 dev ovs-br0 src 172.16.10.6 uid 0
```

**two data streams using different source IPs**

```
section61:~ # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/stdout count=$((1*1024*1024)) bs=1024 | pv | nc 172.16.10.13 42
7.03MiB 0:00:58 [ 120KiB/s] [                                                                          <=>               ]

section61:~ # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/stdout count=$((4*1024*1024)) bs=1024 | pv | nc 172.16.10.15 42
 135MiB 0:01:17 [1.76MiB/s] [                                        <=>                                                 ]
```

to check the traffic shaping of qdisc classes I strongly recommend running [bmon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bmon)

hints:

- if you use "ceil" at class 1:20, then you have to create two data streams at the same time to fully saturate 1:10! otherwise 1:20 will get the unused reminder of 1:10
- using "iptables mangle .. match-set" to classify packets should be working too.

HTH
Regards!

Stefan K.

*openSUSE Leap 15.1 - Linux 4.12.14-lp151.28.75-default*